# SimpleXMLelement with namespaces

Tags: php, xml

I havent worked a lot yet with the XML combined with PHP, but since I am receiving XML back after a SOAP call, I guess I have to deal with it.

Alright. So I get back the following:

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/jRecordBroadcastRowWS" xmlns:bcr="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/jRecordUtils" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:body>
        <queryrequestsresponse>
            <result>
                <bcr:customid>REQ16569</bcr:customid>
                <bcr:externalid xsi:nil="true">
                    <bcr:recordid>a035700001CM60kAAD</bcr:recordid>
                    <bcr:requestid>a1J5700000857EYEAY</bcr:requestid>
                </bcr:externalid>
            </result>
            <result>
                <bcr:customid>SRQ100784</bcr:customid>
                <bcr:externalid xsi:nil="true">
                    <bcr:recordid>a033E000001PxfAQAS</bcr:recordid>
                    <bcr:requestid>a1J3E0000000GSaUAM</bcr:requestid>
                </bcr:externalid>
            </result>
        </queryrequestsresponse>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

So I tried to get the recordid's. However it's not being stored in the recordid's

```
$xmlresponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response); 
$recordid = $xmlresponse->children('soapenv', true)->Body->queryrequestsresponse->result->children('BCR', true)->externalid->recordid;
var_dump($recordid);
```

Just be sure (since i use BCR as capitalize) to make sure I got it right, i did a vardump after I retrieved the getNamespaces(), which resulted in the following.

```
array(4) { 
["soapenv"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
[""]=> string(58) "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/jRecordBroadcastRowWS" 
["BCR"]=> string(49) "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/jRecordUtils" 
["xsi"]=> string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
}
```

So how do I get these ID's parsed out, Did i put the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML with mixed namespaces is hard. Using XPath is easier:

```
foreach ($xmlresponse->xpath('//bcr:recordid') as $sxe) {
    echo (string) $sxe . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a035700001CM60kAAD
a033E000001PxfAQAS
```